# The value for property 'resValues' cannot be changed any further. after upgrading gradle from 4.1.3 to 4.2.1

Tags: java, android, kotlin, heap-analytics

After upgrading gradle from 4.1.3 to 4.2.1 I started getting this error while building the app

> The value for property 'resValues' cannot be changed any further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just update to [1.9.2](https://developers.heap.io/docs/android-changelog#192-2021-06-07)

> [1.9.2] 2021-06-07 Fixed an issue where the Gradle plugin would
> fail with AGP 4.2 due to an IllegalStateException ("The value for
> property 'resValues' cannot be changed any further.")

It turns out to be a problem with `heapanalytics` after removing `apply plugin: 'com.heapanalytics.android'` fixes the problem.

so you could remove `heapanalytics` or delay the gradle update and continue using 4.1.3 until the heap team fixes this issue.

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67729413/3998402):

> Nora from Heap support here! Our mobile team has prioritized this issue and is actively working on a release version with support for Android Studio 4.2. The current release timeline for the supported version is by the end of this June.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error when trying to set a resValue inside a `project.afterEvaluate {` block. After upgrading to 4.2 I was just able to remove the afterEvaluate and it now works.

Comment: It worked for me. removing project.afterEvaluate bloack and remaining inside code resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In heapanalytics [1.9.2](https://developers.heap.io/docs/android-changelog#192-2021-06-07) the issue is fixed